# Adding column with information from another dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two dataframes and I need to join informations.

Here the first df where I have different points (1,2,3..):

```
      eleno elety resno
        1     N     1
        2    CA     1
        3     C     1
        4     O     1
        5    CB     1
        6    CG     1
```

The second one indicates distances between points, "eleno" represents the first point and "ele2" the second one:

```
    eleno  ele2    values
   <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
     1      2       1.46
     1      3       2.46
     1      4       2.86
     1      5       2.46
     1      6       3.83
     1      7       4.47
```

I'd like to have in the 1st df a new column with info from df 2. For example, for point 1 I'd like to have -2(second point):1.46(distance) , -3:2.46, -4:2.86 and so on,  preferable in a one column.

Something like this

```
      eleno elety resno  dist
        1     N     1   -2:1.46, -3:2.46, -4:2.86 ...
        2    CA     1
        3     C     1
        4     O     1
        5    CB     1
        6    CG     1
```

Thank you!

Comment: `merge(df1, df2)`?

Comment: also take a look at [various joins](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) with `dplyr` (you had that tagged)...for example, you could do `inner_join(df1, df2)` that would include rows in both `df1` and `df2` matched by `eleno`

Comment: I used dplyr as tag because I supposed that it could be used for my problem but I'm not able to code with it... So, do you know how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your preference to one column, then a possibility without `dplyr` is as follows. First, we create the new column by concatenating the `ele2` and `values` columns from `df2` using the `paste()` function, with a colon as the separator:

```
new_column <- paste(-df2$ele2, df2$values, sep = ":")
```

Then, we use `cbind()` to bind it to `df1`:

```
new_df1 <- cbind(df1, ele2_values = new_column)
```

This will give us a new data frame like so:

```
  eleno elety resno ele2_values
1     1     N     1     -2:1.46
2     2    CA     1     -3:2.46
3     3     C     1     -4:2.86
4     4     O     1     -5:2.46
5     5    CB     1     -6:3.83
6     6    CG     1     -7:4.47
```

Here is the data that I used, based on what you have given:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    eleno = 1:6,
    elety = c("N", "CA", "C", "O", "CB", "CG"),
    resno = rep(1, 6)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
    eleno = rep(1, 6),
    ele2 = 2:7,
    values = c(1.46, 2.46, 2.86, 2.46, 3.83, 4.47)
)
```

---

If we want to get this column as a single element for each point, we can modify our code in the following manner:

Instantiate `new_column` as an empty vector:

```
new_column <- vector()
```

Then call some variant of `*apply()` or use a for loop to subset the original data frame by points, while applying our original code and appending our *singular* character elements back to `new_column`:

```
lapply(unique(df2$eleno), FUN = function(x) {
    subset     <- subset(df2, eleno == x)
    new_elem   <- paste(-subset$ele2, subset$values, sep = ":", collapse = ", ")
    new_column <<- c(new_column, new_elem)
})
```

Once this operation is complete, we use `cbind()` as before to bind `new_column` to `df1`:

```
new_df1 <- cbind(df1, ele2_values = new_column)
```

Our output is as follows,

```
  eleno elety resno                                                                                                                   ele2_values
1     1     N     1  -2:1.13703411305323, -3:6.22299404814839, -4:6.09274732880294, -5:6.23379441676661, -6:8.60915383556858, -7:6.40310605289415
2     2    CA     1 -2:0.094957563560456, -3:2.32550506014377, -4:6.66083758231252, -5:5.14251141343266, -6:6.93591291783378, -7:5.44974835589528
3     3     C     1  -2:2.82733583590016, -3:9.23433484276757, -4:2.92315840255469, -5:8.37295628152788, -6:2.86223284667358, -7:2.66820780001581
4     4     O     1 -2:1.86722789658234, -3:2.32225910527632, -4:3.16612454829738, -5:3.02693370729685, -6:1.59046002896503, -7:0.399959180504084
5     5    CB     1   -2:2.18799541005865, -3:8.10598552459851, -4:5.25697546778247, -5:9.14658166002482, -6:8.3134504687041, -7:0.45770263299346
6     6    CG     1   -2:4.56091482425109, -3:2.65186671866104, -4:3.04672203026712, -5:5.0730687007308, -6:1.81096208281815, -7:7.59670635452494
```

Here is my **random** data that I used for `df2` in this case:

```
set.seed(1234)
df2 <- data.frame(
    eleno = rep(1:6, rep(6, 6)),
    ele2 = 2:7,
    values = runif(length(rep(1:6, rep(6, 6)))) * 10
)
```

Comment: It's not perfectly what I need because for point 1 (eleno = 1) I have multiple distances calculated, not only one. Values you reported as a new column are only for eleno = 1. Look at the edited question pls